# Centripetal force on a rotating bead

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Imagine a bead that is fixed on one end of a rod, the other end of the rod is free to rotate about a pivot. If someone taps on the bead, then the bead will start to rotate about the pivot point. There must be some centripetal force on the bead. Where does it come from? I've found some similar posts but most of them are answered using fictitious force, which does not really answer my question. Fictitious forces are not real. What exactly is this centripetal force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rod is constrained to maintain a fixed length (as a rigid body) and in order to enforce this constraint tension must develop internally which acts on the bead as centripetal force (due to Newton's 3rd law).

If you separate the parts to show the internal forces,  you will see exactly this. Note the equal and opposite pairs of forces acting between parts.

[image: fig1]

If you cut the rod, then it can't transmit force anymore and its length will extend as the bead will follow a straight line instead of an arc.

Answer (score 0):

The centripetal forces come from the cohesive forces holding the rod together, along with the forces from the pivot holding the rod in place.

If the rod were weak and could provide no force, then the bead would just fly off when struck.